# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Tags: android, database, sqlite

this is the error code:

```
09-27 11:56:01.425: WARN/System.err(10324): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
09-27 11:56:01.435: WARN/System.err(10324):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
09-27 11:56:01.435: WARN/System.err(10324):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
09-27 11:56:01.435: WARN/System.err(10324):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1809)
09-27 11:56:01.435: WARN/System.err(10324):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResource.updateItem(CMSResource.java:1103)
09-27 11:56:01.435: WARN/System.err(10324):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdater.updateItems(CMSResourceUpdater.java:178)
09-27 11:56:01.435: WARN/System.err(10324):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdater.loadUpdates(CMSResourceUpdater.java:102)
09-27 11:56:01.435: WARN/System.err(10324):     at de.enough.appmate.dbase.CMSResourceUpdaterRunnable.run(CMSResourceUpdaterRunnable.java:32)
09-27 11:56:01.435: WARN/System.err(10324):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

and this is the method that is used

```
this.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO itemGalleryItems (id, imageCaption, imageUrl,itemID,orderIndex,displayInGallery) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?); ",
                        bindArgs);
```

the binArgs looks like:

```
String[] bindArgs = {
        (String) imageItem.get("id"),
        (String) imageItem.get("imageCaption"),
        (String) imageItem.get("imageName"),
        (String) item.get("id"),
        (String) imageItem.get("orderIndex"),
        (String) imageItem.get("displayInGallery")};
```

hope someone can help

thanx
newone

Comment: in someone field defined the constraint which will not full fill when you insert the value check the constraint. please display your table structure here with so we can see what constraint are failed

Comment: I had the same problem, but for me, [this][1] worked.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117685/android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-fai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you have autoincrement field, you shouldn't include it in the query... is the "id" autoincrement?

Comment: well, try it, just remove the id from the arguments and the query

Comment: look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568062/stupid-error-android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-co)

Comment: I don't have autoincrement, but I have "text not null" for my columns.  Does that matter?

Comment: if you have `text not null` you must provide value for this field

Answer (score 8):

I have fixed this error;

instead of

```
long sucess = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_CONTACT_EXTRA, null, row);
```

use this to insert data in database

```
long sucess = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME_CONTACT_EXTRA, null,
                row, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at your insert statement. Does it have all the columns that are declared to be not null in table create statement?
And try no to use "id" column, use "_id" instead.

Comment: when i change id to _id than I get this failure : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table itemGalleryItems has no column named _id: , while compiling: INSERT INTO itemGalleryItems (_id, imageCaption, imageUrl,itemID,orderIndex,displayInGallery) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);

Comment: Changing id to _id was a reccomendation. If you provided an id column name in your table's create statement than you'll have to use id in all other statements.

Comment: look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568062/stupid-error-android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-co)

Comment: Show your create table statement.

Comment: In my case I was not binding a value for primary key. By adding that, I got rid of the problem.