# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failedexception

Tags: android, database, sql-insert

I created a table named *resources* but when I insert values in it, this exception is thrown:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:
error code 19: constraint failedexception
```

Here is my *create table* statement:

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + table_resources + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    KEY_TYPE text, KEY_ENCODING text, KEY_WIDTH text, KEY_HEIGHT text, 
    KEY_DATA text, KeyIId text)";
```

The following is my *insert* code:

```
JSONObject show = data.getJSONObject(i);
if (show.get("type").equals("resource_updates")) {
    JSONArray resources = show.getJSONArray("resources");
    try {
        System.out.println("length of resources is is " + resources.length());
        for (int resourceIndex = 0; resourceIndex < resources.length(); resourceIndex++) {
            type = resources.getJSONObject(resourceIndex).getString("type").toString();
            encoding = resources.getJSONObject(resourceIndex).getString("encoding").toString();
            data1 = resources.getJSONObject(resourceIndex).getString("data").toString();
            id = resources.getJSONObject(resourceIndex).getString("id").toString();
            try {
                width = resources.getJSONObject(resourceIndex).getString("width").toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                width = "null";
            }
            try {
                height = resources.getJSONObject(resourceIndex).getString("height").toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                height = "null";
            }
            db.insert(type,encoding,width,height, data1,iid);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e + "exception");
        System.out.println("exception in  the resources");
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where could be the problem?

Comment: When you expect others to debug your code, its best if you provide the entire stacktrace.

Comment: make sure,is your table properly created?i think,your create query is having problem too. you didn't give a white space after table name in your create query.also column names you are using to retrieve data from table are different than you are using those in create query.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Constraint failed usually indicates that you did something like pass a `null` value into a column that you declare as `not null` when you create your table.

Comment: Could you post your `insert` method as well? I assume it's a helper method that calls the actual `SQLiteDatabase.insert` method with your data

Comment: perfect solution for table without primary keys!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get more information about SQLite errors, one can use ADB dumpsys:

```
adb shell dumpsys dbinfo -v
```

combined with grep:

```
adb shell dumpsys dbinfo -v | grep executeForLastInsertedRowId
```

or grep'ed twice:

```
adb shell dumpsys dbinfo -v | grep executeForChangedRowCount | grep failed
```