# sqlite error inserting data in table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm inserting data in table, when db is created first time the data is inserted successfully, but when app is closed and re-launched it gives me error:

```
Error inserting id=1 new=1 title=sample page previous=0 color=0 next=2 state=1 header= "";
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1582)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
at com.testjsonparse.MainActivity.parseAndIsertData(MainActivity.java:108)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

This is the code I'm using in my `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    dataSource = new ContentsDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();
    parseAndIsertData();

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    dataSource.open();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(MY_TAGT, "OnPuse() called");      
    dataSource.close();
}
private void parseAndIsertData() {
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    MyJSONParser jParser = new MyJSONParser();

    contentDataObject = new ContentDataObject();        
    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(BASE_URL); 

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contents
        jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(MOBILE_CONTENT);          
        // looping through All Contents
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

            contentDataObject.setId(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt(MOBILE_CONTENT_ID));
            contentDataObject.setTitle(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_TITLE));
            contentDataObject.setFulltext(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_FULLTEXT));
            contentDataObject.setState(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt(MOBILE_CONTENT_STATE));
            contentDataObject.setNewValue(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt(MOBILE_CONTENT_NEW));
            contentDataObject.setHeader(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_HEADER));
            contentDataObject.setColor(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt(MOBILE_CONTENT_COLOR));
            contentDataObject.setNext(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_NEXT));
            contentDataObject.setPrevious(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(MOBILE_CONTENT_PREVIOUS));

            contentDataObject = dataSource.create(contentDataObject);

            Log.i(MY_TAGT, "Data Inserted " + contentDataObject.getId() + " Times");

        }           

        //textView.setText(builder);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`EDIT` Code for Inserting data into `db` is :

```
// Insert into Database

    public ContentDataObject create( ContentDataObject dataObject) {
        // Content class
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_ID, dataObject.getId());
        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_TITLE, dataObject.getTitle());
        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_FULLTEXT, dataObject.getFulltext());
        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_STATE, dataObject.getState());
        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_NEW, dataObject.getNewValue());
        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_HEADER, dataObject.getHeader());
        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_COLOR, dataObject.getColor());
        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_NEXT, dataObject.getNext());
        values.put(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_PREVIOUS, dataObject.getPrevious());

        long insetId = database.insert(DBHelper.MOBILE_CONTENT_TABLE_NAME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);// Here it gives me error for SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE
        dataObject.setId(insetId);
        return dataObject;

    }
```

`EDIT` Create Table Query is :

```
private static final String MOBILE_CONTENT_DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + MOBILE_CONTENT_TABLE_NAME + "( " + MOBILE_CONTENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
        MOBILE_CONTENT_TITLE    + " TEXT, " +
        MOBILE_CONTENT_FULLTEXT + " TEXT , " +
        MOBILE_CONTENT_STATE    + " INTEGER , " +
        MOBILE_CONTENT_NEW  + " INTEGER, " +
        MOBILE_CONTENT_HEADER   + " TEXT , " +
        MOBILE_CONTENT_COLOR    + " INTEGER , " +
        MOBILE_CONTENT_NEXT + " TEXT , " +
        MOBILE_CONTENT_PREVIOUS + " TEXT );";
```

now I'm unable to find why is this error occurring. Thanks

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117685/android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-fai

Comment: read this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567362/android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-fai and this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499201/sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-failed

Comment: show the code where you inserting the data into the database.

Comment: Also post your `create table` query with all the constraints specified.. May be there is issue of primary key constraint, some records with the same IDs are getting inserted, throwing an error. Make sure the records are not getting added multiple times as you re-run the app.

Comment: Show create table query.

Comment: In your table creation "MOBILE_CONTENT_ID" is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,so in insert query don't put value to "MOBILE_CONTENT_ID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got this error because your table has field MOBILE_CONTENT_ID has primary key and is auto incremented.and you are altering the primary key.you have 2 options
1. Remove primary key for that field
2. Don't insert value in auto incremented field.

Answer (score 3):

In your table creation "MOBILE_CONTENT_ID" is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,So in insert query don't put value to "MOBILE_CONTENT_ID".